# Getting insights from Azure Video Analyzer using an IP camera(no iot edge capability) live stream

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I want to use an IP camera without iot edge support to live stream the video footage to azure and I want to get insights from video using Azure Video Analyzer for Media(aka VideoIndexer).

I have came across 2 possible ways to achieve it in Azure-

1. Came across [LiveStreamAnalysis](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/blob/main/media-functions-for-logic-app/LiveStreamAnalysis.md) GitHub repo but the functions are not getting deployed as it is using older version of Media Service(v2). However, I read the newer version of Media Services but didn't found the Live Stream sample to start with.
2. Found [Video Analyzer(preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-docs/cloud/get-started-livepipelines-portal?tabs=portal) documentation but I am only able to stream and record the live stream using a simulated IP camera live stream.
   I want to do further analysis on video by using video indexer apis but I didn't find any way to achieve it using 2nd approach.It only explained using IOT edge device pipelines and worflows.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for bringing (1) to our attention.
I reached out to the relevant contact.

There isn't other built in integration your (2) option is using Azure video analyzer (not for media) which is a different service.

The most promising path at the moment is (1) based on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding (1), I am the main author of the Live Stream Analysis sample and it is true that the functions need to be updated to use AMS v3 API, and the logic apps to be updated too to use these new functions. I started the work to build the new functions but the work is not complete. They will be posted to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-dotnet-core-functions-integration/tree/main/Functions
You can see that there is a SubmitSubclipJob which will be key for the sample.

Comment: Yes, I can use SubmitSubclipJob function in the new repo. Can you tell me ,how I can get the subclip Url to index the clip using VideoIndexerv2 api in the logic app?